# surefire parallel threadCount is ignored (JUnit 4)

Tags: junit4, maven-surefire-plugin, parallel-testing

I've seen quite a few topics dealing with running JUnit tests in parallel with maven surefire, but I haven't seen an answer dealing with this particular issue.

In short: test methods are executing in parallel (good news there), but the  prop doesn't serve to limit my threads. The ultimate goal is to parallelize my web driver and appium runs, but I'd like to be able to control the total possible threads first.

The code snippets below are from a dummy project just for demonstration's sake. Following the [apache documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html/), it doesn't look like there's a whole lot more to it than the below.

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <threadCountMethods>2</threadCountMethods>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

ExampleTest.class

```
public class ExampleTest {

    @Test
    public void one() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @Test
    public void two() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @Test
    public void three() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @Test
    public void four() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @Test
    public void five() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @Test
    public void six() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @Test
    public void seven() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @Test
    public void eight() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @Test
    public void nine() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @Test
    public void ten() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

I'd expect a full run of this class with the provided pom config to take a little longer than 25 seconds (10 sleeps for 5 seconds running two at a time). The actual runtime is a little more than 5 seconds:

```
Tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.022 sec - in ExampleTest
```

Changing that threadCountMethods prop has no effect on the runtime (it looks like all methods are going in parallel without regard for the threadCount prop).

Any input would be greatly appreciated; thanks!

Comment: I am digging this and ran a very similar case as yours. And it also confused me that the threadCount number is exceeded as if ignored. What I also found is the value of parallel matters, e.g. use classes and methods have different behaviors according to threadCount setting. It does't work for classes. But still haven't figure it out clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So after some more digging, I found a tiny little property called `perCoreThreadCount` found [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html). If not specified, that prop defaults to `true`. With a total of 8 cores on my machine, 2 threads per core (from the original pom config in the question) would mean up to 16 of those sample tests could run in 5ish seconds. Adding that prop and setting value to `false` in pom fixed all the trouble!